# Can extensions methods be called on no-object?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Why does the following piece of code work?

call:

```
SomeObject sO = null;
bool test = sO.TestNull();
```

code:

```
public static bool TestNull(this SomeObject sO)
{
    return sO == null;
}
```

Is this allowed to work or just a bug?

Comment: this `null.TestNull();` shouldn't compile

Comment: I believe it should be `sO.TestNull()`

Comment: I think you meant `bool test = sO.TestNull()` while sO is null?

Comment: Its not a valid code to compile.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes - I think this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl yes. it should be sO.TestNull();

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I imagine the downvotes were added before the question was corrected so that it compiles.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well, on one hand it's a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459427/why-allow-extension-methods-on-null-objects) and on another hand it says "Why does the following piece of code work?" and follows it with code that doesn't work

Comment: @Habib Correct. But surely `((SomeObject)null).TestNull();` compiles and works.

Comment: @Offler: Please spend more time checking your question before posting it in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you meant

```
bool test = sO.TestNull();
```

Then the answer is just that static functions do not need an instance of the object. Also, calling an extension function is just syntactic sugar for calling the function with parameters.

edit:

I recommend also reading [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266774/1094268).

Answer (score 13):

> Is this allowed to work or just a bug?

The code after you've edited the question (to call `s0.TestNull()` instead of `null.TestNull()` is meant to work, yes.

Extension methods are *just* syntactic sugar for calling static methods as if they're instance methods. So a call of:

```
s0.TestNull()
```

is converted into

```
ClassContainingExtensionMethod.TestNull(s0)
```

... and that's all. No nullity checks are performed automatically.

This can actually be really useful - imagine if [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) had been an extension method - then instead of writing:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo))
```

you could write the more readable:

```
if (foo.IsNullOrEmpty())
```

However, this power should not be taken lightly - *most* extension methods should throw `ArgumentNullException` if the first parameter has a null value, and those which don't should be *very* clear about it. (It should be relatively rare for such a method *not* to include `Null` somewhere in the name.)

Comment: @Moho: This is a compile error. You cannot _compile_ the code `null.TestNull()`. (You could however write `((SomeObject)null).TestNull()`)

Comment: @Moho: Really? Did you actually try compiling it? I did: "Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type '`<null>`'" Note that this was before the question was changed to use `s0.TestNull()`

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know wether i can use it for extension methods for comparision of special objects => if s0 = null && a second object which is also put to the extension method is null, both have equal values, therefore it should return true.

Comment: @Offler: I didn't quite follow that, but hopefully the answer was useful anyway - it's basically fine to do this.

Comment: @Offler: you can. The extension method is not really called on that object, it is just about some tricky parameter passing. Your first parameter written as "this Type param" can be NULL.

Comment: @Moho: No, even with a parameter type of `object` it still won't compile when you use a null literal as `null.TestNull()`.

Comment: @Moho: the point here is the `null literal`. That is, precise syntax of `null.Method( .. )` - it is disallowed. If you write it differently, even as `((object)null).Method()`, it is NOT the same, and it is correct!

Answer (score 4):

The code should be `bool test = sO.TestNull();`. And yes, that is supposed to work.

You are extending an object with a function, it doesn't matter if the object is `null` or contains a value. It's essentially the same as writing `SomeStaticClass.TestNull(sO);`

Answer (score 2):

As Jon and others already pointed out, this is standard behaviour. It can be useful for

- Extension methods that raise events and check for nullity before doing so
- Extension methods that provide chains of *Maybes* where  each part of the chain could be null.

Long time ago I wondered whether [it is OK to send messages to null references](http://realfiction.net/go/121) but time has shown that this is a pretty pragmatic and useful, especially considering the fact that in other languages null references simply do not exist.