# LINQ SingleOrDefault() equivalent

Tags: javascript, linq, typescript, typescript1.5

In Typescript, I use this pattern often:

```
class Vegetable {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {
    }
}

var vegetable_array = new Array<Vegetable>();
vegetable_array.push(new Vegetable(1, "Carrot"));
vegetable_array.push(new Vegetable(2, "Bean"));
vegetable_array.push(new Vegetable(3, "Peas"));

var id = 1;
var collection = vegetable_array.filter( xvegetable => {
    return xvegetable.id == id;
});
var item = collection.length < 1 ? null : collection[0];

console.info( item.name );
```

I am thinking about creating a JavaScript extension similar to the LINQ [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274) method where it returns `null` if it's not in the array:

```
var item = vegetable.singleOrDefault( xvegetable => {
    return xvegetable.id == id});
```

My question is whether there is another way to achieve this without creating a custom interface?

Comment: There are some momentum in this direction. See https://linqjs.codeplex.com/ and http://lord-saumagen.github.io/TS

Answer (score 51):

You can always use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in this way:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const [notFoundItem] = arr.filter(id => id === 4); // will contain undefined
const [foundItem] = arr.filter(id => id === 3); // will contain 3
```

**Edit**
My answer applies to `FirstOrDefault` and not to `SingleOrDefault`.
`SingleOrDefault` checks if there is only one match and in my case (and in your code) you return the first match without checking for another match.

BTW, if you wanted to achieve `SingleOrDefault` then you would need to change this:

```
const item = collection.length < 1 ? null : collection[0];
```

into

```
if (collection.length > 1)
   throw "Not single result....";

return collection.length === 0 ? null : collection[0];
```

Comment: I use the additional [0] notation if I know that the collection would always yield a single result. And yes, the behavior for SingleOrDefault would throw an error if the collection yields more than one. Typescript has been a game changer for us and I'm looking forward for more C# like features to find it's way there. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to find one item in array, I suggest you to use [ES6 find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), like so:

```js
const inventory = [
    { name: 'apples', quantity: 2 },
    { name: 'bananas', quantity: 0 },
    { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
];

const result = inventory.find(fruit => fruit.name === 'cherries');

console.log(result) // { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

It's faster and easier to read, because you don't need to write `collection[0]`.

By the way, C#'s `SingleOrDefault` throws an exception if it found more than one element. Here you're trying to make a `FirstOrDefault` extension.

Answer (score 2):

If reuse is not necessary, you could implement a `singleOrDefault` by applying a simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

In this case the **reducer** function is only calculated when the array is not empty. It throws when the length is greater than 1, otherwise it returns the only element. When the array is empty, the default value parameter of the reduce function is returned: in this case `null`.

For example:

```
[].reduce(function(acc, cur, idx, src) {
  if (src.length > 1) {
    throw 'More than one found';
  }
  return src[0];
}, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce for this:

```js
// add as prototype
Array.prototype.singleOrDefault = function(filter) {
  return this.reduce(function(current, next) {
    if (filter && !filter(next))
      return current;

    if (current)
      throw 'The input sequence contains more than one element';

    return next;
  }, null);
}

// test cases
const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1];
console.log("input: " + input);
console.log("Test 1 (=4 => found): " + input.singleOrDefault(m => m == 4));
try {
  input.singleOrDefault(m => m == 1);
}
catch(err) {
  console.error("Test 2 (=1 => error): " + err);
}
try {
  input.singleOrDefault();
}
catch(err) {
  console.error("Test 3 (without filter => error): " + err);
}
console.log("Test 4 (one item + without filter => found): " + [10].singleOrDefault());
```