# Can I somehow create a function that looks like .toUpperCase()?

Tags: javascript

Instead of using

```
function functionName(arg){
arg = 1;
}
name(arg);
```

I want to use something like the .toUppercase() function

```
function functionName(){
this = 1;
}
arg.name();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your question make zero sense to me. Can you try to rephrase it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: I really can't get what you mean but you may mean somthing like arg.toString().toUpperCase()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write an extension method in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354298/how-do-i-write-an-extension-method-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the prototype of the string object in JavaScript

```
String.prototype.functionName = function () {
    return this; //do whatever you want to do it with the string
};
```

Now you are able to call this way `mystring.functionName()`

Comment: While it's true that it's possible to do that, you shouldn't _ever_ have to do that.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you. @davmich its not about it being optimized, recommended or conventional. Its just to prove a point and I just wanted to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

add function inside the object

```js
var arg = {
  name:function(str){
    return str;
  }
}

console.log(arg.name('sss'))
```