# How can I reuse function chains in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, gremlin

I'm using a functional library ([Gremlin](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/)) to query a graph database. Invoking it looks like this:

```
g.V().has(...).out(...).hasLabel(...).in(...).next();
```

Some of my functional chains are very long, and I'd like to be able to reuse pieces of them for DRY purposes. For example:

```
const postProjection = () => (
  project("id", "title")
  .by(__.id())
  .by("title")
)

g.V().hasLabel("post").postProjection().next()
```

I know this doesn't work but that is the concept. I want to encapsulate a piece of this chain into a function that I can (somehow) inject into various other function chains from this library where needed. By dynamically constructing these calls with reusable segments I could dramatically cut down on repetition.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call it using your exact syntax, you'd have to add functions to the `Vertex` (or whatever) prototype using something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9354310/389146).  That's sort of verbose, though, and not really the expected way to solve something like that. I would recommend making it a regular function call, for which your existing solution is pretty close except for needing a parameter:

```js
const postProjection = (vs) => (
  vs
  .project("id", "title")
  .by(__.id())
  .by("title")
)

const vs = g.V().hasLabel("post")
postProjection(vs).next()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a type that implements functor and lets you invoke methods of the inner object:

```js
const foo = i => (console.log(i), {foo, i});

const Box = o => ({
  map: f => Box(f(o)),
  run: (k, ...args) => Box(o[k] (...args)),
  get: o
});

const fun1 = o =>
  o.foo(3).foo(4)

const fun2 = o =>
  o.foo(7).foo(8);

console.log(
  Box(foo(1).foo(2))
    .map(fun1) // lift normal function into the type
    .run("foo", 5)
    .run("foo", 6)
    .map(fun2)
    .run("foo", 9)
    .get // escape from the type
    .foo(10));
```