# C# to Typescript equivalent of extending a class method

Tags: c#, typescript

I am new to typescript. I want to extend a class to have a function similar to this. I have this code in C# but I want it to write in typescript

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByPropertyName<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string attribute, string direction) {
    // my logic here
}
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: To be clear, you're saying you want to extend a class *separate* from the class's original definition, right? (Since what you've shown is a C# extension method.)

Comment: Closely related, but doesn't handle the type aspect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354298/how-do-i-write-an-extension-method-in-javascript

Comment: [Possible generic approach](https://hackernoon.com/a-extension-method-experiment-on-typescript-8o44t36xy)