# Add attribute to instance of "Number"

Tags: javascript

I want to see if a number is a multiple of `π`. So ideally it would behave exactly like an ordinary number, but with extra functionality:

```js
>>> pi
3.14...
>>> pi.isMultipleOfPi
true
>>> b = pi * 5
>>> b.isMultipleOfPi
true
```

With wishful thinking

```
>>> c = pi + 1
>>> c.isMultipleOfPi
false
>>> d = pi + 2 * pi
>>> d.isMultipleOfPi
true
```

Is there a way to achieve something like that in Javascript? I think this would be pretty straight forward in Python, but there seems to be no way to create overloads for addition/multiplication etc. in JS. If there were, I could simply extent the `Number` class.

Setting something on `Number.prototype = function` also doesn't seem to work as it sets it for the entire class and not on an instance.

Comment: "*Is there a way to achieve something like that in Javascript?*" I'm sure there is; what have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Questions in the form of "*is X possible?*" or "*is there a way to do X?*" are generally not good fits for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. See [ask]

Comment: You could add a non-enumerable getter to `Number.prototype`, but I don't see any benefit over just passing the number to a function.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use the result of `number % Math.PI === 0` to verify if something is a multiple of Pi? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is [this](https://melvingeorge.me/blog/extending-datatypes-javascript) any help?

Comment: @esqew I have tried extending the number class, setting an attribute directly, setting on Number.prototype etc. After a lot of googling, I wasn't able to find a way to do it. Thus, I felt asking if is this even possible was valid. Sorry about that.

Comment: So you want to set this on just **one specific number**? The main issue with that is that 99.9999999999998% of all numbers you work with in JavaScript are primitives, not objects, and so they don't have any properties (the ones they seem to have only come from `Number.prototype`, which the JavaScript engine will use if you try to access a property on a number primitive. You could instead make an accessor property on `Number.prototype` that determines if the number it's called on is a multiple of PI and returns the right flag, that would give you the syntax you showed, but on all numbers.

Comment: @esqew The problem is that `Math.sin(Math.PI)` does not return `0`. I would wish to define my own class `π`, which would check is this is indeed a multiple of `π` and return exact value from a table. However, I still need it to behave as a normal number in every other situation.

Comment: @Tommi Sadly, I don't see how that can help. Because if I do an arithmetic operation on an extended `Number`, I get a normal `Number`, and not the extended class.

Comment: I think that other than the ideas in the answers below, you're trying to do something that simply cannot be done in JavaScript. Subclassing the Number class won't do you much good, as virtually all code that does numeric computation involves number primitives, not Number instances. You'll probably a lot happier retracing your decisions and finding another approach to solving whatever actual problem you have.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How would that accessor property look like? Because `Number.prototype = function(){ return self % Math.PI ~ 0 }` is not what I'm looking for. I would wish to distinguish between `3.14` vs `3.14` with `isMultipleOfPi` property. The former would be literally a float with 2 significant digits, but the 2nd one would behave in exactly the same way for arithmetic operations, but I would be able to check if it's actually a multiple of `π` in some special cases.

Comment: Yea, you can't do that. Values of type `number` are not instances of any "class".

Comment: @KarloSpacapan - The only way to do that is to use `Number` objects rather than primitives, as I describe in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought at first you wanted to do this for all numbers, which is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354298/how-do-i-write-an-extension-method-in-javascript).

But if you only want to do this for one specific number, you *can*, but you probably won't want to. 99.9999999999998% of all numbers you work with in JavaScript are primitives, not objects, and so they don't have any properties (the ones they seem to have only come from `Number.prototype` [or, in turn, from `Object.primitive`], which the JavaScript engine will use if you try to access a property on a number primitive).

You could make a number object instead, and put the property on that:

```js
const c = new Number(Math.PI);
c.isMultipleOfPI = true;
console.log(c);
console.log(String(c));
console.log(c.isMultipleOfPI);
```

The problem with that, though, is demonstrated by the `console.log(c);` line above. With Chrome's devtools (and perhaps others), you see this:

```
{
    isMultipleOfPI: true,
}
```

rather than `3.141592653589793` as you might be expecting.

The reason is that `c` is an *object*, not a primitive, and some things that use it (such as `console.log`) may treat it primarily as an object rather than primarily as a number.

Math and string concatenation work, though:

```js
const c = new Number(Math.PI);
c.isMultipleOfPI = true;
console.log(c * 2);
console.log(c - 2);
console.log(c + 2);
console.log(c / 2);
console.log("The number is " + c);
```

Just beware that `Number` instances (objects) are objects, and that very, very little code is written explicitly to work with them properly. Most code using numbers expects number *primitives*.

Alternatively, you could make an accessor property on `Number.prototype` ([Pointy shows you how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223850/157247)) that determines if the number it's called on is a multiple of PI and returns the right flag. That would give you the syntax you showed, but on all numbers. But it *is* a function call, so accessing the property works it out each time. Just having a `isMultipleOfPI(num)` function might be clearer.

In a comment you've written:

> Because `Number.prototype = function(){ return self % Math.PI ~ 0 }` is not what I'm looking for. I would wish to distinguish between `3.14` vs `3.14` with isMultipleOfPi property.

The only way to do that is to use `Number` objects rather than number primitives, as described above.

Comment: Thank you, this mostly works! Sadly, for my use case I was really hoping there would be a way to control addition/subtraction.

Comment: @KarloSpacapan - Afraid not. :-) You can get *close* with [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), but JavaScript fundamentally doesn't have operator overloading.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add properties to *specific* number values; they are not objects and thus they can't have any properties. You *can* add properties to the Number prototype, as follows:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "isMultipleOfPi", {
    get: function() {
      return this.valueOf() % Math.PI === 0;
    }
});

const pix2 = Math.PI * 2;
console.log(pix2.isMultipleOfPi);
console.log((7).isMultipleOfPi);
```

That adds a Number prototype property defined with a "get" function so that the code you posted will work as you expect. The method will be available for all numbers in your program, which doesn't seem like a bad thing if you want that feature at all.

Note also that extending built-in prototype objects is frowned upon by many people. In my example, I extended the prototype in a way that ameliorates some of the problems with extended prototypes.