# What's the meaning of "T" (TArg0, TEnum, TInt) in extension methods?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I can define an extension method to determine if an object is null

```
public static bool IsNull(this object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

But I can also do this:

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(this T obj) {
    if(obj == null)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Both are being applied to every object. What's the purpose of this T? To further elaborate what type is being expected? If yes, why this: `typeof(T)` is possible? <del>And what's the reason behind `(this T obj) where T: int)` (***where***) then?</del> (*this doesn't work anyway as pointed out by @MatthewWatson*)

So many questions.

Comment: You can't have `where T: int`, it's a compile error. Where did you see that?

Comment: Did you [read the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)?

Comment: [Generic Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) and [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Aside: the function can (and **should**) be written as `return obj == null;` instead of that three-line `if` statement that you have. What’s more, that code is actually correct for argument type `object` but incorrect for `T` – in the latter case you instead need to write `object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)`, you cannot use `==`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought those were really the same; can you show an example where they are not?

Comment: @TimS. So they are, my mistake. They are *not* the same for non-generic types that overload `operator==`, which is why I was misled (NB: the observable effect *should* be the same for a proper implementation of `operator==` …).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right, C# generics don't work like C++ templates: the method doesn't get compiled for every instantiation, it gets compiled once, for all possible instantiations. `==` is resolved to the built-in reference comparison before the concrete type is known. About your NB: do you really mean to suggest that given two strings, say `s1` and `s2`, it is poor design that `s1 == s2` compares the characters that make up the strings? The observable effect is different from `object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)`.

Comment: @hvd I’m aware of that. I just committed a brain fart. Concerning the NB: `object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)` implies `s1 == s2`, not necessarily the other way round. That’s what I meant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, okay, so to put it another way, `x == x` for all `x`? If so, pretty much agreed, any `x` for which `x == x` compiles but returns `false` will cause enough problems that you'd better have a *really* good reason for doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `T` is a type argument for a Generic method.

See here for MSDN documentation about generics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

It's not specifically to do with extension methods; it's just to do with generics.

Answer (score 3):

T means generic. It means that the type is not known. By default its an object as everything is an object in .Net. But you can specialize T with where paradigm. For instance where T is IDisposable. Then your function will only apply to IDisposable types.

Answer (score 1):

`T` historically means `Type`. It is used by convention to define generic (in C++ - template) paramteres.
In you example it is not necessay because any object in .NET infrastructure inherits base `object`.

But remember good old days of C++, when C# even wasn't introduced. C++ has only plain type without common parent (i.e. `object`). So developers was forced to use something to tell to compiler "here something will be substituted, actually I don't know what exactly, but later, at compile-time it will be clear. Do it for me, please".

Returning to notation, in MFC another prefix was used - `C` like `CString`.

**UPD:** You first example will not works because it is extension and `null` object has not any methods, even you `IsNull`.

**UPD1:** Do not read UPD above, the cake is lie.

Comment: @AlexGP what do you mean by "will not works"?. It works perfectly fine: `String myObj = null; Console.WriteLine(myObj.IsNull)` ==> "True"

Comment: @Alex : that is not right , you can look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847209/in-c-what-happens-when-you-call-an-extension-method-on-a-null-object for explanation.

Comment: @Atrotygma ahh, you area absolutely right, I am afraid of nulls a bit =)

Comment: @srsyogesh my fault, I forgot how this sample compiled to IL.