# Create Array.ReturnLength() extension method?

Tags: c#, arrays, extension-methods

I would like to create an extension method for the `System.Array` class that will take in a `char[]` or `byte[]` array and return its Length. I need this method for in case the array is null, and I don't want to litter the code with whole bunch of `(arr == null) ? 0 : arr.Length` calls.

I want to call it like this: `Array.ReturnLength(arr)`.

I tried implementing it, but I only see it when I do `arr.ReturnLength()`, but not as an Array method.

```cs
public static int ReturnLength(this Array arr)
{
    if (arr == null)
        return 0;
    return arr.Length;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do is a static extension method. C# doesn't sport those. Static methods require an instance. Instead, since there is no real syntactic difference use your own class and put static methods there.

Comment: This is why people use empty arrays to represent "no data" rather than nulls... i.e. `int[] array = new int[0];` rather than `int[] array = null;`

Comment: You: _I only see it when I do `arr.ReturnLength()`,_ What more do you want? It works like an extension method should, then. What is the name of the static class you have put your method into? Your method is a member of that class. Your method is not a member of `System.Array` (even if it "extends" `System.Array`).

Comment: `arr != null ? 0 : arr.Length` ... 0 length means *the array is there and it's empty* while null array means *the array doesn't exist*, it's not the same thing ! Watch out for any implication!

Comment: Why `arrays`? Isn't it better to use [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a generic extension method:

```
public static int ReturnLength<T>(this T[] arr)
{
    if (arr == null)
        return 0;
    return arr.Length;
}
```

You can use it with a null reference:

```
string[] arr = null;
int length = arr.ReturnLength(); // 0
```

**Update**: but your non generic extension method should work the same way:

```
public static int ReturnLength(this Array arr)
{
    if (arr == null)
        return 0;
    return arr.Length;
}
```

This works because extension methods are just syntactic sugar. Actually they are static methods which you could also use via class name:

```
int length = MyExtensions.ReturnLength(arr);
```

[In C#, what happens when you call an extension method on a null object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847209/in-c-what-happens-when-you-call-an-extension-method-on-a-null-object)

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer. What would be a reason for choosing the generic over the non-generic method?

Comment: I think in this case it doesn't matter. You don't need to know what type `T` is since the only information you need is the `Length`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, C# doesn't allow for static extension methods. 
However, extension methods are just syntactic sugar, and you are allowed to call them as static methods off of the class they are defined *in*, rather than instance methods off of the object they are defined *on*.

You already know you can call your method via `arr.ReturnLength()`. You can also call it via `MyExtensionsClass.ReturnLength(arr)`, where `MyExtensionsClass` is the static class in which `ReturnLength` is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone. You're right. All I need is `arr.ReturnLength()`. It'll handle nulls also. Just felt weird calling it if `arr` is null.