# CS1720 warning erroneously(?) generated for extension method

Tags: c#

Consider the following program:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Extension(this string str)
    {
        if(str == null)
            Console.WriteLine("String is null");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("String is not null");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        default(string).Extension();    // <--- warning
        Extension(default(string));     // <--- no warning
    }
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
String is null
String is null
```

But, the C# compiler gives a CS1720 warning on the first marked line:

*warning CS1720: Expression will always cause a System.NullReferenceException because the default value of 'string' is null*

My question is: **Why would the compiler suggest there will be a NullReferenceException?** The first call to `Extension()` is equivalent to the second one, but the second does not produce a warning. Both calls ought to be safe because `this string str` is a parameter, which can safely be null, as seen in the second line. I have been able to reproduce this on the 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5 compilers, but not Mono 3.0.7.

Comment: It is just a bug, [reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/695362/c-compiler-gives-incorrect-warning-expression-will-always-cause-a-system-nullreferenceexception-for-extension-methods).  They didn't look in a hurry to fix it back then.

Comment: You could add a `#pragma warning disable 1720` (with a nice comment describing why).

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the answer is yes, the warning is incorrect. You have proven that quite well. (Probably that is the reason it is a warning after all)

As [discussed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847209/in-c-what-happens-when-you-call-an-extension-method-on-a-null-object) it doesn't harm to call an extension method with a `null` value. I guess the compiler team didn't get through all the hussle to check whether the method to call it an extension method or not.

Comment: Indeed, the implementation of the warning may predate the extension method feature.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are de-referencing a null object, in the second case you are calling a method with a null argument.

==update==

Let me re-state, yes this doesn't appear to be a legitimate warning.  I suspect the compiler is issuing a warning because it believes that deref'ing a null object is "bad".  The warning likely pre-dates the extension method feature.

It would be interesting to see how Roslyn breaks it down.

Comment: The two lines are functionally the same.

Comment: Yes, but I imagine the compiler still sees this as the deference of a null object.  I suppose Roslyn might provide more info.

Comment: Right, that is the question. Why does the compiler see that as a dereference?

Comment: Well even smart compilers aren't that smart.  I suspect it has a check for default(object) that is followed by a deref and issues a warning.