# Operator ?. and extension methods

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Extension methods with `.` operator always called, even if object is null without throwing `NullReferenceException`. By using operator `?.` it will never called. For example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = null;
        a.b(); // works
        a?.b(); // doesn't work
    }
}

public class A { }

public static class ext
{
    public static void b(this A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm called");
    }
}
```

Why extension method isn't called in this case? Is this an ambiguos feature?

Comment: You can see the compiled>decompiled code at [Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAobAHYAIwBswBjGM4gQxBBgAUAnAeyievWwG9sZ+YBEuRgpqyEQDcWYACYwAstUgAKAJR8BvATpgBBGNRgBeGBGDFiOXQOoA6QuswwA9C5gB3FkwDWITTbUAPwOTq7usiyoIBAA5Mie3j4BMAC+2On4RKQUVLT0BtxpuEI5osjiInl0MKgAHsg8KaUiYhIU0nIwjsgAFmAFhho62jYwAMIsECAsxKh2AOpMYGgAMpCoKgBEAJKx6JTUlqiyW2rWAumpQAAA)

Comment: Well `?.` operator checks if value is `null` *before* doing anything, so why it should work ?  Something to read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847209/in-c-what-happens-when-you-call-an-extension-method-on-a-null-object        and     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: What is the practical usage of having extension method which doesn't use this object at all.

Comment: I don't understand why there is not `NullReferenceException` at `a.b();`?

Comment: @Shaharyar, because nothing is being invoked on `a`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your expression a?.b() which uses
**?.** operator translates to equivalent:

```
if(a != null)
{
  a.b();
}
```

so this is why your method does not get called.

Answer (score 1):

Calling an extension method has the following edge-case:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11893-extension-method-invocations

> Note: Unlike an instance method invocation, no exception is thrown when expr evaluates to a null reference. Instead, this null value is passed to the extension method as it would be via a regular static method invocation. It is up to the extension method implementation to decide how to respond to such a call.

This explains why your compiler will make `a.b()` work (it emits a `call` IL op). And it's probably save to assume that the `a?.b()` will actually include a runtime null check, thus not executing the method.