# Is there a particular reason why string.IsNullOrEmpty() is not an extension method?

Tags: c#, string

C# has [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Some static methods of the `string` class can be rewritten as extension methods e.g. [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netcore-3.1).

Is there a reason why there are no default extension method for the `string` class that provide the same functionality as the static class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A really good one.

It PREDATES the existence of extension methods. It simply was there first.

There are quite some similar scenarios around. Lots of API taking a typeof but not having a generic version, i.e. - all predating generics.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to) documentation (specifically, the "Applies to" section).

This method existed since .NET Framework 2.0.

If you look at the history of C# from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-30), you can simply find that extension methods came with C# 3.0, which was around .NET Framework 3.5.

**Note:** Don't mix between C# versions and the .NET versions.

Answer (score -4):

Another reason is the method would fail if the string reference was null.  Consider something like this:

```
string x = null;
if (x.isNullOrEmpty()) ...
```

This call would obviously cause an error.

Comment: Nope. Actually calling an extension method with a null this is legal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847209/in-c-what-happens-when-you-call-an-extension-method-on-a-null-object