# C# null checking extension method on sub-object does not work

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullreferenceexception

I have a null-checking extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrEmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

which is nice to call to avoid extra null checks before running a loop, like this

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int sum = 0;
foreach (int i in intArray.OrEmptyIfNull())
    sum += i;
```

But in case the IEnumerable I'm using is inside another object, it will fail with NullReferenceException, if the surrounding object is null - like here

```
foreach (int i in object?.intArray.OrEmptyIfNull())
    sum += i;
```

After reading the discussion in [In C#, what happens when you call an extension method on a null object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847209/in-c-what-happens-when-you-call-an-extension-method-on-a-null-object/847211#847211) I understand the compiler translates the expression to

```
ExtensionClass.OrEmptyIfNull(object?.intArray)
```

But I experience a NullReferenceException here if object == null.
Why?

Doesn't this behavior make any use of null-checking extension methods very dangerous?

Comment: `(object?.intArray).OrEmptyIfNull()`

Comment: *"compiler translates the expression to ..."* - it doesn't translate to that because of short-circuiting.

Comment: Your method is never called if `object` is null because of short-circuiting, i.e. the expression `object?.intArray.OrEmptyIfNull()` is always `null` if `object` is null.

Comment: you could do a null check before foreach and thus save cpu-cycles by not creating non-enumeratable enumerables

Comment: If caring about some CPU cycles, it would be better to do C++ instead of .net...

Answer (score 3):

Your extension method is never called if `object` is `null` because of short-circuiting, i.e. the expression `object?.intArray.OrEmptyIfNull()` is always `null` if `object` is `null`. `intArray` is not even evaluated in this case.

A cleaner approach would be to actually check the reference before trying to iterate:

```
if (object?.intArray != null)
    foreach (int i in object.intArray)
        ...
```

Or, at least in this particular case, you could always use LINQ:

```
int sum = object?.intArray?.Sum() ?? 0;
```

Comment: This answers my "why" question.
My intention was to avoid the if statement before executing the loop on an enumerable, which might be null. So your solution is obvious, but just says my approach makes no sense in case it is a sub-object.

My second question if it is dangerous leads into what best practice there is?

Comment: I guess it's opinion based but IMO the best solution is to always check if the `IEnumerable` is `null` instead of relying on the implementation of an extension method.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're getting confused between [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and [Nullable Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types).

Nullable reference types are simply that type. Since `object` is a reference type, you just have an object. If you dereference a null reference type, you get an exception. If you know for a fact that `object` is not null at runtime, you can override the compiler with the syntax ...

> object!.intArray

for example. But, why would you do that? Obviously, in your case, object is null. Just check it.

Comment: My intention was to avoid the if statement before executing the loop on an enumerable, which might be null. In this case I apparently cannot apply this approach :-((

Comment: @Nick It's not intArray that's null, it's object.

Comment: Final solution is either to add the if before running the loop or to insert brackets like proposed by @madreflection: (object?.intArray).OrEmptyIfNull()