# String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) Vs myString != null

Tags: c#, string, null-string

Which one is better among these three?

```
string myString = ""; 
String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString);

vs

string myString = "";
if(myString.Length > 0 || myString != null)

vs 

string myString = "";
if (m.Length > 0 | m != null)
```

Former is clearer but is there any performance difference among these? What if, in case a string is never empty, like if taken from a Text Box, which could be empty but not null ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, the version in the question:

```
if(myString.Length > 0 || myString != null)
```

would ***definitely*** be worse, as you should test for `null` **first** (not second) - ideally short-circuiting on `null` so you don't attempt to call `.Length`. But generally I'd just use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. You could always write an extension method to make it less verbose if you want (you can call extension methods on `null` values).

```
static bool HasValue(this string s) {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, nice tip that last one. I am a bit of a sucker for string.Format extension methods :)

Comment: Great one always, never thought about it.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I realize the method is static, but when calling it on an instance variable not everyone may be able to tell if such call will throw a null reference exception or not.

Comment: @Esteban - the compiler / runtime can tell, though ;-p

Comment: I agree with Esteban, the syntax is not 100% clear to the uninitiated. In an attempt to make this clearer, instead of naming the extension method 'HasValue' I would instead name it exactly the same as the static method: 'IsNullOrEmpty', which is allowed:

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string s)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }

Comment: The extension method should start with `if (s == null) throw new NullReferenceException()` (not `ArgumentNullException`). If it looks like an instance method, it behaves like an instance method. If you want it to allow a `null` argument, then call it statically.

Comment: @Z280Z28: No, that's not right. You should never throw a 'NullReferenceException' in your own code. Extension methods are static methods and therefore should throw an 'ArgumentNullException' (if you are going to throw one -- the examples here should return true or false and not throw). For more on this see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463302/argumentnullexception-or-nullreferenceexception-from-extension-method.

Comment: I've often wondered why this method doesn't already exist for `String`. If I had a dollar for every time I've had to write `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString))` I'd be a rich man.

Comment: performance tests are here: http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2006/12/08/string.empty-null-length-or-string.isemptyornull.aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell The name of the method is wrong - HasValue. Empty string is also a value.

Comment: @anario that depends on the context. If I showed you a birth certificate with a name that was zero characters long, and asked you whether that person had a name: would you say "yes"? But indeed, the name could be less ambiguous. But I'll let you into a secret: *the above works just fine for us* (the exact usage is described in the intellisense comments, etc)

Answer (score 4):

Go with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)`. It's clearer and more succinct. It will not be a bottle-neck in your application.

If you only need to check for string "emptiness", then I would go with a check against `string.Empty` since it expresses your intent better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the IsNullOrEmpty.

It will be easier to parse when you are looking through the code later on.

Here's another - slightly bizarre - reason. Some later programmer is bound to come along later, scratch his beard and say "I think that myString.trim().Length != 0 is better" and change it.

As others have pointed out: checking for null second is a potential null access error waiting to happen - the library routine is guaranteed to be ok.

Comment: Hence the creation of `IsNullOrWhitespace`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, IsNullOrEmpty() is superior to the manual checks for purposes of maintainability and isn't likely to suffer in performance thanks to the JIT compiler's runtime decisions about inlining (see [Eric Gunnerson's comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64644.aspx)).

In case anyone else is wondering what the actual .NET implementation looks like, here is the .NET 4 code:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return (value.Length == 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

That attribute indicates the method will also be inlined in NGen (that is, native) images.

Comment: Interesting, **ILSpy.exe** shows that **mscorlib** -> **System** -> **String** -> **IsNullOrEmpty(string): bool** looks like this: **`return value == null || value.Length == 0;`**.

Answer (score 1):

The `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is the better choise if you are unsecure about how to test the different states of the string reference (which you obviously are, as you got it wrong... ;).

Using the `IsNullOrEmpty` method:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) ...
```

is equivalent to using a short circuit test for null and zero length:

```
if (s == null || s.Length == 0) ...
```

If you know that the referene can't be null, you can skip that check and just check the length:

```
if (s.Length == 0) ...
```

The `IsNullOrEmpty` method would also work for normal situations, but in the case where something went wrong and the reference is actually null, the `IsNullOrEmpty` method would silently accept it, while you would normally want to be made aware of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the String.IsNullOrEmpty(String s) is implemented as:

if (s == null || s.Length == 0) ...

in the API.

Comment: ... which means as far as IL code goes, the same IL is generated.  Neither is faster than the other.

Comment: I am not sure if this ok to put it here, but using Disassembler, this is what is in the API for String.IsNullOrEmptr(value) {
    if (value != null)
    {
        return (value.Length == 0);
    }
    return true;}

Comment: That's probably an artefact of disassembling rather than how the code actually looks.

Answer (score -4):

> `I believe the String.IsNullOrEmpty(String s) is implemented as:
>   if (s == null || s.Length == 0) ...
>   in the API.`

That's wrong. Try it and you will get an exception as the two statement will be tried. If s is null, then s.Length will throw an execption.

Comment: `||` short-circuits, so no, the second expression won't be evaluated if `s` is `null`. Also, not an answer.