# Null checks on extension methods that do not need an instance?

Tags: c#, null, extension-methods

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193505/design-choice-do-i-want-extension-methods-to-throw-exceptions-on-null) on the subject, which was closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463302/argumentnullexception-or-nullreferenceexception-from-extension-method) - as was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152305/extension-methods-null-object-behaviour) before mine. However, I want to ask a more specific question on a corner case that I feel none of the above questions, or their answers, really covers:

**How should an extension method *that doesn't really need an instance* react to null references?**

An example (where the answer is obvious) would be the `.IsNullOrEmpty()` (which of course should just return `true` on a null reference), but I believe there might be other cases where it makes sense to call an extension method on an object that might be null.

Another example could be a variation of the method I outlined in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193505/design-choice-do-i-want-extension-methods-to-throw-exceptions-on-null), if we for a minute assume that the `foreach` loop will not throw on a null collection (I know it does, but imagine it doesn't just as a thought experiment).

What would be best practice here? Should we check for null and throw `ArgumentNullException` anyway, or does it depend on the case? If it does depend on the case, on what criteria should we decide what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I have an issue with extension methods that do not throw on a null instance.  I understand that extension methods are syntactic sugar for static methods.  However, their use is like that of an instance method.  Hence, I believe they should behave as if they were an instance method and throw when the "this" instance is null.

This is a maintainability concern for me.  For a newcomer to a code base who does not know whether a method is on the actual type or is an extension method, seeing a method like IsNull() would be disconcerting because it simply doesn't make any sense.

So, that is my two cents: a complete utter personal opinion.

Comment: +1. Exactly. Extension methods are syntactic sugar that makes a static method look like an instance method. So it should *act* like an instance method as much as possible, and that includes throwing an exception if the `this` argument is `null`.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, even though I don't agree with you - the community has spoken :P

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly, this is what you're saying:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ....
}

public static class MyClassExtension
{
    public static void MyClassExtensionMethod1(this MyClass obj, string name)
    {
        if(obj == null)
        {
            // what to do here, since obj is not used anywhere in this method
        }

        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

I think it depends on your school of thought.

Since `MyClassExtensionMethod1` doesn't use the `MyClass` object at all, you can skip the check, and skip notifying client code (or users).

Before going further, I would ask myself, what is the point of having this extension method in the first place, if it doesn't reference an instance of the class passed in?

I would just suggest one of the two following approaches:

If you can modify the code, and this method belongs to MyClass, make MyClassExtensionMethod1 a method in `MyClass`. Of course, this means that the instance will not be null, so you're changing your expectations :)

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...

    public MyClassMethod1(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

...Or, if you really, really don't need the MyClass instance, move this method to another class, independent of `MyClass`:

```
// not an extension class
public class MyOtherClass
{
    public void MyOtherClassMethod1(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Even if you keep your extension method (and whether it throws or not), I suggest adding good documentation on your decision, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of where I intentionally introduced an extension method to deal with `null`.

```
public class Foo {
    public int Time { get; set; }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static int? GetNullableTime(this Foo foo) {
        if (foo == null)  return null;    // Cast is implicit.
        return foo.Time;
    }
}
```

Makes it nice when you're using this all over in some property initializer. You tell me what looks better.

```
var b1 = new Bar{
    T1 = (foo1 == null) ? (int?)null : foo1.Time,   // Note, cast is *required*
    T2 = (foo2 == null) ? (int?)null : foo2.Time,
    T3 = (foo3 == null) ? (int?)null : foo3.Time,
};

var b2 = new Bar{
    T1 = foo1.GetNullableTime(),
    T2 = foo2.GetNullableTime(),
    T3 = foo3.GetNullableTime(),
};
```