# What should I throw when the `this` parameter is null in extension methods?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

What should I throw when the `this` parameter is null in extension methods?

If I should throw `ArgumentNullException`, what should the name of the parameter be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArgumentNullException or NullReferenceException from extension method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463302/argumentnullexception-or-nullreferenceexception-from-extension-method)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, throw an `ArgumentNullException`, and provide whatever the name of your parameter really is.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could consider doing nothing about it, because  what will happen is a NullReferenceException will be caused in the extension body for that parameter, which is actually exactly what the semantics appear like on the usage of the extension method.

Comment: +1; Not a bad thing to consider, but the alternative will always be more clear (See Fyodor's answer).  I think it really depends on who the consumer of the extension method will be.  If the method is part of a public facing API, I'd explicitly throw.

Comment: Good point; I agree. I thought I'd actually added a comment to this effect, but I guess not! hehe

Answer (score 1):

In the end extension methods are kind of just fancy static methods so I'd take the same approach you would with them