# Cannot find Any method of IEnumerable<> to do empty check

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a method where I am returning `IEnumerable<Data>` and I wanted to check whether `IEnumerable` is null/empty or not. I did some research and it looks like we can use `Any` method of it but in my code I don't see any `Any` method in it so that means I am running older version of .Net?

Now I am using above method as below -

```
private bool Process()
{
    IEnumerable<Data> dataValue = GetData();
    // check if dataValue is null or empty
    if(dataValue != null) {
        // process entry
    }
}
```

What can I do to check if `IEnumerable` is null or empty in my case?

**Update**

```
private bool Process()
{
    IEnumerable<Data> dataValue = GetData();
    if(dataValue = null || !dataValue.Any()) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach (var x in dataValue)
    {
        // iterating over dataValue here and extracting each field of Data class
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your `.cs` file.

Comment: `null` is not the same thing as being-empty, and `.Any()` will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the `IEnumerable<T>` is `null`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538243/why-doesnt-any-work-on-a-c-sharp-null-object - you will need to use the **Elvis Operator**, like so: `Boolean hasAny = enumerable?.Any() ?? false;`.

Comment: Or create your own Extension `IsNullOrEmpty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for an *explicit* `Any` check or `null` check.

```
foreach (var x in (dataValue ?? Enumerable.Empty<Data>()))
```

is what I would suggest, since it avoids the double enumeration problem of using `Any` (and it treats `null` as equivalent to empty). So this might look like:

```
private bool Process()
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    IEnumerable<Data> dataValue = GetData();
    foreach (var x in (dataValue ?? Enumerable.Empty<Data>()))
    {
        returnValue = true;
        // iterating over dataValue here and extracting each field of Data class
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Any() is an O(1) operation. And if you look at the source it enumerates to the first item then returns true if it found one.

Comment: @JoshBerke If the underlying enumerable was `IQueryable` (e.g. getting from a database) then `Any` will cause an extra DB query (similar issues can occur if it is a `yield return` solution etc). And there is no guarantee that the data used in `Any` will be the same data used in the `foreach` (for example). You may wish to read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932548/multiple-enumeration-and-use-of-any and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240844/handling-warning-for-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable .

Comment: Ok, I don't deal with any IQueryable implementations that hit the DB (At least not a normal basis). And glad I don't, seems like a nasty side effect that is counter intuitive.

Comment: @JoshBerke It is by design and well documented.

Comment: just because its intentional and well documented doesn't mean its a good implementation. It's a side effect that as your writing the code you might be unaware. If I was to write a library that consumed an IEnumerable, and I had to do multiple enumerations on it for some reason, and developer comes along and sends an IQueryable....

Comment: @JoshBerke The issue isn't _just_ with `IQueryable`. It is a risk with many enumerables (example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xsvtdu - note that `Any` "lost" the second 1). The point is `Any` does not guarantee it is `O(1)`, despite your assertion, and it doesn't guarantee it doesn't enumerate (which when you think about it is intuitive - it _has_ to enumerate in some cases to work out if there is an entry or not). Explaining the finer details to you is hard in a comment-based context. If you write up a new question I can add an answer for you there, or point you to some good resources.

Comment: No need, your fiddle was a great example.

Answer (score 0):

Usually

```
dataValue != null && dataValue.Any()
```

You may have to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
if (dataValue?.Any()==true)
{}
```

I wish you could just say

```
if(dataValue?.Any())
```

but that won't compile:-)

Comment: `if(dataValue?.Any() ?? false)` - just provide a default value to get the `bool` from your `bool?`. somehow looks cleaner than `==true`

Comment: I dunno still looks funny. If blocks should work on nullable<bool> types.

Answer (score 0):

We use a following method that is similar to LINQ's `Single()` extension, provided enumeration should not be empty:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Required<T>(this IEnumerable<T>? source)
  {
    var empty = true;

    if (source != null)
    {
      using var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

      while(enumerator.MoveNext())
      {
        yield return enumerator.Current;

        empty = false;
      }
    }

    if (empty)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Source should be non empty.");
    }
  }
```

It's virtue in that it passes enumeration once.