# Why ArgumentNullException? Why not System.NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, argumentexception

See line of code below:

```
DataTable [] _tables = null;

// Throws System.NullReferenceException
_tables.GetType();

// Throws System.ArgumentNullException
_tables.Count();
```

In this lines of code I have `_tables` reference and trying to access its system define functions `GetType()` and `Count()`, both throw exception but why `.Count()` throws `System.ArgumentNullException`, since we have same value for reference which is `null`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArgumentNullException or NullReferenceException from extension method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463302/argumentnullexception-or-nullreferenceexception-from-extension-method)

Comment: @280Z28 I think in that que, Patrik Hägne ask for "best exception type to throw when an extension method called on a null instance"...

Comment: http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/16/null-parameters-in-extension-methods/

Comment: @AnkushMadankar The accepted answer in that question explains not only the accepted practice that results in your call getting an `ArgumentNullException`, but the reason why that practice was originally chosen.

Comment: @280Z28 If I know practice used in `ArgumentNullException` , I never ask this question, rather search for practice and got answer for same, but while asking I wasn’t aware about that practice.. I already search for similar question but wasn’t found any one hence put this question.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar It's ok to ask a duplicate question, *especially* if you already searched and couldn't find it (different name, didn't know what you were looking for, etc., etc.). :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) on `IEnumerable<T>`, declared in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) - so you're *actually* calling:

```
Enumerable.Count(_tables);
```

... so `_tables` *is* a method argument, and it makes sense for the exception to tell you that. You're not actually dereferencing the `_tables` variable when you call `Count()`, whereas you *are* when you call `GetType`.

Comment: What do you mean by "dereferencing the `_tables` variable"?

Comment: It means getting the actual value of the reference - dereferencing (since a reference is just a pointer to an address).

Comment: Clear every concept mention in this answer by experts..! `extension method` I found most intersting. Thank u all for knowlegeful replies.

Answer (score 7):

Because `Count` here is a call to an extension-method with `_tables` as the argument - it is actually:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(_tables);
```

If you don't want to use the extension method: use `_tables.Length`.

Answer (score 4):

`Count()` is an extension method (it should therefore throw an ArgumentNullException if a passed in value is null and null is illegal), not a method on the instance of the object i.e. `Count` is defined as `public static int Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)`.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's an extension method, and not an instance method.

As it's compiled to `Enumerable.Count(_tables)`, it doesn't apply to `NullReferenceException`, so it just throws an `ArgumentNullException` instead. However, `GetType` is an instance method, so you are trying to call a method on `null`, which... um, doesn't work.